# Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in .../common.inc on line 7924 on drupla site migration

Tags: entities

I am migrating a site hosted on on Drupal 7.22, apache 2.2.22aa and php 5.6.9 from one linux server to another lunx server. I did a back up of mysql and apache htdocs folder and extract it on the destination server. But when I lunched the page on the server, I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in .../common.inc on line 7924

I enabled the debug as below

```
/*
 * Get the entity controller class for an entity type.
 */
function entity_get_controller($entity_type) {
  $controllers = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  if (!isset($controllers[$entity_type])) {
    $type_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
    $class = $type_info['controller class'];

    // add debug.
    if(gettype($class) == 'string' || gettype($class) == 'object') {
      $controllers[$entity_type] = new $class($entity_type);
    } else  {
      print_r(debug_backtrace());
    }
    $controllers[$entity_type] = new $class($entity_type);
  }
  return $controllers[$entity_type];
}
```

Now I am getting the error as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => ../includes/common.inc [line] => 7891 [function] => entity_get_controller [args] => Array ( [0] => node ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => ../modules/node/node.module [line] => 952 [function] => entity_load [args] => Array ( [0] => node [1] => Array ( [0] => 15 ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] => ../modules/node/node.module [line] => 971 [function] => node_load_multiple [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 15 ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => ) ) [3] => Array ( [file] => ../includes/menu.inc [line] => 593 [function] => node_load [args] => Array ( [0] => 15 ) ) [4] => Array ( [file] => ../includes/menu.inc [line] => 761 [function] => _menu_load_objects [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [path] => node/% [load_functions] => a:1:{i:1;s:9:"node_load";} [to_arg_functions] => [access_callback] => node_access [access_arguments] => a:2:{i:0;s:4:"view";i:1;i:1;} [page_callback] => node_page_view [page_arguments] => a:1:{i:0;i:1;} [delivery_callback] => [fit] => 2 [number_parts] => 2 [context] => 0 [tab_parent] => [tab_root] => node/% [title] => [title_callback] => node_page_title [title_arguments] => a:1:{i:0;i:1;} [theme_callback] => [theme_arguments] => a:0:{} [type] => 6 [description] => [position] => [weight] => 0 [include_file] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => node [1] => 15 ) ) ) [5] => Array ( [file] => ../includes/menu.inc [line] => 472 [function] => _menu_translate [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [path] => node/% [load_functions] => a:1:{i:1;s:9:"node_load";} [to_arg_functions] => [access_callback] => node_access [access_arguments] => a:2:{i:0;s:4:"view";i:1;i:1;} [page_callback] => node_page_view [page_arguments] => a:1:{i:0;i:1;} [delivery_callback] => [fit] => 2 [number_parts] => 2 [context] => 0 [tab_parent] => [tab_root] => node/% [title] => [title_callback] => node_page_title [title_arguments] => a:1:{i:0;i:1;} [theme_callback] => [theme_arguments] => a:0:{} [type] => 6 [description] => [position] => [weight] => 0 [include_file] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => node [1] => 15 ) ) ) [6] => Array ( [file] => ../includes/menu.inc [line] => 1755 [function] => menu_get_item [args] => Array ( ) ) [7] => Array ( [file] => ../includes/menu.inc [line] => 1770 [function] => menu_get_custom_theme [args] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [8] => Array ( [file] => ../includes/common.inc [line] => 5292 [function] => menu_set_custom_theme [args] => Array ( ) ) [9] => Array ( [file] => ../includes/bootstrap.inc [line] => 2212 [function] => _drupal_bootstrap_full [args] => Array ( ) ) [10] => Array ( [file] => ../index.php [line] => 25 [function] => drupal_bootstrap [args] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) ) )
```

Comment: Dumping a stack trace (especially one that isn't indented) isn't going to help anyone discover your problem. You need to find the class in question and understand why Drupal can't find it. `dpm` or `print_r` `$class` instead.